# How to Export from Proquest.com Flow, Bibliography to BibTeX .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, export

I'm using the https://flow.proquest.com product (Refworks replacement).  I'd like to export my Flow bibliography database to the BibTex `.bib` file.  How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) There is no LaTeX-specific format for bibliographic entries. Do you maybe mean "BibTeX-formatted entries? I'm afraid I don't have a university-sponsored email account and hence can't sign in to proquest.com.

Comment: Indeed: I do have access to Flow _via_ my employer and I'd say BibTeX isn't on their radar at all: no import or export visible.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, which is to select the collection folder or references.

Then menu > More > Export references > Select BibTex > Click export

The a file named `export.bib` will be downloaded.